# Unity 3D Mobile and Windows Azure

Tags: android, ios, azure, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game using Unity 3D. The target will be Windows Phone (eventually), Android and iOS.

I know the Windows Azure SDK is probably written in C#. When I try to import the DLL, however, it appears to rely on .NET stuff that is not part of the Unity .NET. I have run into this before. Unity is mainly 2.0 .NET. There are some 3.5, 4.0 and even 4.5 stuff, but it is all experimental and mostly doesn't work well.

My question is whether I can get access to the source code (C#) of the Azure DLL?

If not that then can someone please help me with the C# raw calls that I would need to make to access all of the Azure web services for a Azure Mobile instance?

I know there is an iOS Obj-C way of doing it, but I would prefer using straight C# so it will be cross platform to both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're looking for Windows Azure Mobile Services SDK code?  If so, you can download it here:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services

Or, were you looking for the storage or other SDK?

Comment: I believe this is just what I was looking for. It looks like it includes the source code to what goes into the DLL that you get when you download the SDK for Visual Studio. Thank you!

Comment: If you want a Unity library for App Services you can use https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/AppServices